# java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException when validating CSS?

Tags: java, javascript, css

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.profischnell.com%2F&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

I got most of my errors fixed. But I am down to the last few and have not a clue where to go from here.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks so much,
Ken

Answer (score 1):

wrong:

this does not work: double `{{}}`

```
    @font-face {
    {
    font-family : "'Roboto'";
    font-style : normal;
    font-weight : 300;
    src : local('Roboto Light'), local('Roboto-Light'), url(https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v10/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfaCWcynf_cDxXwCLxiixG1c.ttf) format('truetype');
    }
}
```

also
wrong : `font-family : "'Roboto'";`

in this manner

`font-family : 'Roboto';`

and:

```
content: "";
```

right, but it works just as well

```
content: '';
```

**revalidate**
[css-validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_upload) and
*Congratulations! No errors found.*

Comment: Avril. Thanks so much for the help. Can you point me to which css file you edited there? Thanks buddy, I appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not seeing any of that in any of the files that are showing errors thru W3C.

Comment: css file that is in the url you wrote

Comment: Hi Avril. The only place I see any of that code from what I linked above is below the errors and warnings under "Valid CSS"

Answer (score 0):

You have a few opacity set to numbers higher than 1. Opacity ranges 0 to 1. You also have the wrong image property in one of the slides.  And you may want to check your site in Firefox console to see what Javascript is throwing the Exception

Comment: Those opacities are IE filters. They can go up to 100. Ex. 'filter: alpha(opacity=25'

Comment: Ah,  well,  that makes sense. Yet again their bugging out on you.  Maybe you do away with them and use a browser hack.  I'm assuming they're IE filters, are they not?

Comment: Yes LOTUSMS as stated "Those opacities are IE filters." ;)